# SSH from iPhone to Windows, seems to lack permissions

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I am trying to remotely run a Windows program (MultiMonitorTool) from my iPhone to enable/disable monitors. Ideally I'd do it over SSH using Apple Shortcuts, but I'm open to any solution.

I've connected over SSH and I can navigate around. I can also run simple environment variables like:

```
calc
```

which simply opens Calculator on my desktop. But if I try to run other apps (like MultiMonitorTool) that I've also added to PATH) they seem to just start as background processes that hang. I read that using PsExec can solve this, so I've tried the following:

```
PsExec -i MultiMonitorTool
```

if I run this in cmd on the windows machine it successfully launches the app, but if I run it over SSH it again creates a background process that doesn't seem to do anything. I've also tried:

```
PsExec -i -h MultiMonitorTool
```

but I get the error

> Could not start PSEXESVC service on [MachineName]:
> Access is denied.

Any suggestions for debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated.